# Express.js assets not found

Tags: express, pug, assets

I have an express server:

```
//setup Dependencies
var connect = require('connect')
    , express = require('express')
    , port = (process.env.PORT || 8081);

//DB Setup removed for brevity

var server = express.createServer();
server.configure(function(){
    server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    server.set('view engine', 'jade')
    server.set('view options', { layout: false });
    server.use(connect.bodyParser());
    server.use(server.router);
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

And the home page view:

```
server.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render('index');
});
```

Where my folder structure is:

```
server.js
/views/index.jade
/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
/public/javascripts/bootstrap.js
```

However when I try to hit /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css or /public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css I get a 404. Form the examples I can find in the express.js github repo I think I'm setting things up correctly... but I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Did you try to get the stylesheet by calling stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css instead of /stylesheet/... ?

Comment: I was trying to hit the file directly by going straight to the url (stackoverflow wouldn't let me post the full http://localhost url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i get it working whith these conf:

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));  ---> remove the "/"
```

and in your `<head>` request the files like these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
```

the full url should be `http://example.com/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: I can't get it to work in my exising project still but a clean install is working using what you describe. The express examples use it without the slash as well. Going to give you the correct answer since this is syntactically correct :)